# Creating a function that can be used to plot a triangle with an area of 1

Tags: plotting, functions

The function should take an input `x`, which is the absolute value of the bounds of the triangle and should be centered at 0.

I'd like to use `UnitTriangle`, but if there's a better way, please let me know.

I'm not sure how to translate the width to the height.

```
Triangle[x_] := (2*(1/x))*UnitTriangle[x];
Plot[Triangle[x], {x, -2, 2} , PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're on the right track. One problem is that `Triangle` is a built-in function, so when you try to define your own `Triangle` there is the possibility that the definitions will overlap. In fact, you might have seen `SetDelayed: Tag Triangle in Triangle[x_] is Protected.` This is Mathematica telling you that it won't allow you to assign anything to `Triangle`. All built-in Mathematica functions (including things like the imaginary number `I` and Euler's number `E`) start with a capital. The best practice is to always start your own custom definitions and variable names with lower case letters.

The next thing that we can look at is the triangle itself. `UnitTriangle` is a good start, and you're multiplying by 2/x out front, I assume to try to rescale the height which is on the right track. The problem is that when you plot it, x can take on the value of zero, and then you have 2/0. So we can define a new variable which is the width. You have some options as to how to use this horizontal expansion, which I'll call `a`. You can either set it as a global variable `a = 5`, or you can fold it into the definition like this:

```
triangle[x_, a_] := UnitTriangle[a x]
```

Now we have something we can plot and will let us change the width by specifying different values of `a` when we call the function. But we also want to control the height. Larger values of `a` are going to actually decrease the width of the triangle. So `a = 1` gets us a triangle from -1 to 1, `a = 5` gets us a triangle from -0.2 to 0.2, and `a = 1/4` gets us a triangle from -4 to 4. Thus, the larger the `a` value, the narrower the triangle, the taller we need the triangle to be.

Since:

$area = \frac{1}{2} b h$

and $b$ is actually $2/a$, we can replace it in the formula.

$area = \frac{1}{2} \frac{2}{a} h$

$h = area \cdot a$

$h = 1 \cdot a$

So, now we can put that out front of our definition to multiply the height.

```
triangle[x_, a_] := a UnitTriangle[a x]
```

One last thing we might want to do is be able to translate the triangle left or right.

```
triangle[x_, a_, b_] := a UnitTriangle[a(x-b)]
Manipulate[
   Plot[
      triangle[x, a, b],
      {x, -10, 10},
      PlotPoints -> 200,
      PlotRange -> Full
   ],
   {{a, 1}, 0.1, 4},
   {{b, 0}, -5, 5}
]
```

[image: Animation of triangle plot.]

**UPDATE:**

@m_goldberg had a fantastic idea that I didn't even know you could do, so I learned something neat. I figured I would add this to my answer as well since I feel it makes it more complete, despite me plagiarizing their excellent answer.

```
Assuming[a > 0, Integrate[triangle[x, a, b], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 1

Comment: Apparently my gif broke and doesn't play automatically, but if you click on the image, you should be able to see it play.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it with `Piecewise`. Like so:

```
unitTriangle[x_][u_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(u + x)/x^2, -x <= u <= 0}, {(x - u)/x^2, 0 <= u <= x}}, 0]
```

#### Demonstration

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[unitTriangle[x][u], {u, -2, 2},
    PlotRange -> All, Ticks -> {Automatic, Subdivide[0, 1/x, 5]}],
  {{x, 1}, 1/10, 2, 1/10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

#### Update

`unitTriangle` as defined above should be integrable, and it should integrate to 1 over the interval $[-x, x]$ for all $x > 0$.

```
Assuming[x > 0, Integrate[unitTriangle[x][u], {u, -x, x}]]
```

> `1`

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `PDF` of [`TriangularDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TriangularDistribution.html) the area under which is 1:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[PDF[TriangularDistribution[{-a, a}], x], {a, 1, 3, 1/2}], {x, -4, 4}, 
  Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"f[a][x] = ", 
     ToString[PDF[TriangularDistribution[{-a, a}], x], StandardForm]}],
  PlotLegends -> (Row[{"a = ", ToString[#, StandardForm]}] & /@ Range[1, 3, 1/2])]
```

[image]